# "to analysis" or "to analyse"

Tags: verbs, nouns

I've been proofreading a paper and stumbled upon a confusing (for me) grammar problem. I thought there was an error in the following sentence
"Studies have been carried out **to analysis**..." and  I was ready to change it into "carried out **to analyse**"  but I checked the former version on google and it seems to be quite common.

I mean, I'd use **to analysis** in, for example "prior to analysis" but I wouldn't use it in exchange for the proper verb (to analyse).

However I am not a grammar expert. So I would appreciate help (a grammar name for it would be enough, honestly I don't even know how to tag this). Thank you in advance for any thoughts/opinions.

Anna

Comment: Where on google did you find "analysis" commonly used as a verb?

Comment: Well. I googled "carried out to analysis" and lo and behold, even books got that sentence.

Comment: I can find : analysis will be carried out.., but not carried out to analysis: https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&q=carried+out+to+analysis&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQmdOEitXOAhVEzxQKHdU-BGYQ7xYIFygA&biw=768&bih=909

Comment: In cases like this, it's usually helpful to check a dictionary. It's possible that some authors are verbing _analysis_ but the dictionaries will tell you the standard usage. I'd expect that it'd be up to the author to defend their unconventional usage rather than you trying to find excuses for it.

Comment: @Josh61 There: [https://www.google.pl/search?q=%22carried+out+to+analysis%22&oq=%22carried+out+to+analysis%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6480j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8]  Although I'd say I googled errors.

Comment: This study carried out to analysis of HinfI polymorphism in Pit1 in Iranian Sarabi cattle.  -  This is the only sentence I could find

Comment: 'analysis' is a noun, so 'prior to analysis' is a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what google says, *analysis* is a noun, not a verb.  *"Studies have been carried out to analysis..."* is simply wrong.

Looking for things like this on Google can lead to misleading results: you might search for "to analysis", see lots of results, and conclude that it's a common usage.

But, those words would be used together in a grammatically correct way **in a different context**, such as "Highly parallel gene expression analysis has led **to analysis** of gene regulation".  Here, analysis is still a noun, and something else has "led to" it.

In other words, your instincts are correct: use "analyse" for the verb.

Comment: Ah. My gut feeling was correct then. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google finds "carried out to analysis" in many scientific papers.  I think they were merely written by scientists for whom English is not very familiar.  As Max said, it should be "carried out to analyze" (or "analyse" in Britain).

Comment: I agree. But as a non-native  self-taught English speaker - I have always a lingering doubt at the back of my mind, that there might be something I don't know, so I appreciate the feedback.